# How to apply lambda function to column of dataframe correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
data = {'Name':['Tom #111', 'nick #1313', 'krish', 'jack #2 lol'],
        'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And I want to apply a function to get rid of any hastag+numbers.
My code looks like this:

```
df['Name'].apply(lambda x: re.sub("#[-+]?[0-9]+", " ", str(df['Name'])))
```

However this comes out like this:

```
0 0 Tom
1 0 Tom
2 0 Tom
3 0 Tom
```

My expected output is:

```
0 0 Tom
1 0 nick 
2 0 krish
3 0 jack lol
```

I tried to use axis=1 in lambda function but it gives me an error of:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you want to remove hashtag + numbers or hashtag + everything else that follows? If its hashtag + numbers, the last row would be "jack lol"

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing out. I want to keep lol at the end! Just the hashtag and number. I just edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pandas string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas-series-str-replace),

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('#\d+', '')

    Name        Age
0   Tom         20
1   nick        21
2   krish       19
3   jack lol    18
```

If you want to know how to use apply (definitely not preferred over str methods),

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('#\d+', '', x))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: re.sub("#[-+]?[0-9]+", " ", x))
```

1) note where `x` is used

2) you need to store the result back into the dataframe